# PyQt GUI and raw_input?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, raw-input

so I am new to both python and PyQt. I have written two separate files:

1. A simple GUI with 4 buttons
2. A file that takes in user input through terminal

I noticed that every time I click button one, which I've linked to running the test() function in file 2, my GUI just hangs. Ultimately, I would like to program button 1 to run the function test() when clicked, and then if the user presses button 2, it would send a number that I've coded into it.

However, I am wondering if raw_input can even be used this way.

File 1.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import user_input

# ----- GENERAL VARIABLES -------
# Windows Size
w_xSize = 200
w_ySize = 300

# Create a generic btn size
x_size = 130
y_size = 32

# Create generic x,y, variables to append to btn locations
# such  that you can shift the entire btn locations as a whole
x_frame1 = (w_xSize-x_size)/2 #center
y_frame1 = 10

# ------ DEFINING WINDOW PROPERTIES -------
# create our window
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Base class  to all our widget is QWidget
w = QWidget()

# Set window title
w.setWindowTitle('Primitive GUI')

# Set window size.
w.resize(w_xSize,w_ySize )

# ------ DEFINING BUTTON PROPERTIES -------
# Button 1
btn = QPushButton("Channel 0", w)
btn.move(0+x_frame1, 0+y_frame1)
btn.resize(x_size,y_size) #(x,y)

# Button 2
btn2 = QPushButton("Channel 1", w)
btn2.move(0+x_frame1, 30+y_frame1)
btn2.resize(x_size,y_size)

# Button 3
btn3 = QPushButton("Channel 2", w)
btn3.move(0+x_frame1, 60+y_frame1)
btn3.resize(x_size,y_size)

# Button 4
btn4 = QPushButton("Channel 3", w)
btn4.move(0+x_frame1, 90+y_frame1)
btn4.resize(x_size,y_size)


# ------ DEFINING TEXTBOX PROPERTIES -------
textbox = QLineEdit(w)
textbox.move(x_frame1, w_ySize-50)
textbox.resize(x_size,y_size)


# ------ CREATE SLOTS FOR BUTTONS ------
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click():
   print("btn1 was clicked")
   user_input.test()

@pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_btn2():
    print('btn2 was clicked')
    textbox.setText("Button 2")



# ------ CONNECT SIGNALS TO THE SLOTS ------
# Each button can have its own function that it calls

# Button 1
btn.clicked.connect(on_click)

# Button 2
btn2.clicked.connect(on_click_btn2)


# ------ SHOW THE WINDOW ------
# Show the window and run the app
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

File 2

```
def test():
    value = True
    while (value == True):
        user_input = raw_input("enter your command or type exit:")
        if user_input.isdigit():
            print "is a digit"

        elif (user_input == "exit"):
            value = False
        else:
            print "is not a digit"
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on the problem you are facing. It seems that you are trying to mix `pyqt` with the Python CLI's `raw_input`. Why would you do that?

Comment: Your gui will hang until the called function returns.  The way around this is for the called function to do it's work in a separate thread.

Comment: When you click first time you run `test()` which uses `raw_input()` which waits for data from keyboard - and all program waits too - so it hangs. Better use `def test(user_input)` instead of `raw_input`.